# How to get touch joystick in unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, touch, joystick

I want to know how to change this keyboard input to a mobile joystick, here is the code I will be using. I also want the new input system to be implemented with the new joystick. I work with Unity and C#.

```
public float fireRate = 0.5F;
public float speed;
public float tilt;
public Boundary boundary;
public GameObject shot;
public Transform shotSpawn;
private float myTime = 0.0F;
private float nextFire = 0.5F;
private Rigidbody rb;
private AudioSource audioSource;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    myTime = myTime + Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && myTime > nextFire) {
        nextFire = myTime + fireRate;
        Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);

        audioSource.Play();

        nextFire = nextFire - myTime;
        myTime = 0.0F;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.velocity = movement * speed;

    rb.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
    );
    rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
        0.0f,
        0.0f,
        rb.velocity.x * -tilt
    );
}
```

Comment: I haven't read through all of it, but it looks like [this discussion](https://forum.unity.com/threads/create-two-virtual-joysticks-touch-with-the-new-input-system.853072/) and the video that comes with it might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution. use joystick pack from unity, change 2 lines of code

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

to this to work with joystick

```
float moveHorizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
float moveVertical = joystick.Vertical;
```

don't forget to add joystick variable.

```
public Joystick joystick;
```